# Invite Friends Modal for Website off of Facebook

Tags: facebook, web, dialog, invite

How do you allow your Facebook Connected users to invite their Facebook friends to your website?

All previous answers on SO are outdated referencing that it was previously possible with [fb:multi-friend-selector](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/), but since FBML will soon be deprecated, its not an option worth entertaining.

The only option I see now is to create a canvas app that redirects to my website but I would assume this is not permissible since [only Canvas or Mobile apps can use the Requests dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/). I could build my own modal by getting the users friends and then sending them a message directly--also probably not permissible.

Nikolay did a fair assessment [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9721165/ways-to-invite-friends-from-facebook-to-website), but was not provided a solid answer. Is Facebook locking down multiple friend invites and leaving only newsfeed posts and likes to webpages?

Answer (score 0):

I use Social button like recommend and implement it with my site. ref to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: The [Recommend Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) does not prompt the user to select specific friends like the Request Dialog. I want a modal that displays all the user's Facebook friends and allows them to select and invite them specifically.

Comment: That most likely work on Facebook App. but I don't see that for a website now Facebook still have that option for you.

Comment: Sorry Ali, not sure I understand your last response.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to tell you that the option you wanted I can only see its available on Facebook App not website.

Maybe you should try 'send' button instead because it's similar

Answer (score 0):

So, we looked and it appears you cannot use the Invite Friends modal unless you are a mobile or Facebook canvas app.

We did, however, come up with a solution. Using the Open Graph API (see [Publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)) and the publish_stream extended permission, you can post directly to a user's friend's wall. It cannot be a private message (publish_stream does not allow you to change the privacy of the message) but it does allow user's friend to get a notification of the post.

You can see it working in some of our developer's games on [www.pokki.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) that are supporting our Pokki Games API. We came up with a nice modal that shows the user what the message they'll be posting looks like. This puts the user in control so they can click on their friend in a list of all their FB friends and makes the message more genuine (rather than automatically spamming all their friends with disingenuous messages).